# How to list only the data attributes of an object?

Tags: python-3.x, attributes

Given the numpy array a

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5)
```

how can I get a list containing all data attributes of a, but no method attributes?

```
# expected to be part of list
a.shape
a.size
a.ndim

# expected NOT to be part of list
a.sum()
a.all()
a.max()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5)

attribute_list = [attribute for attribute in dir(a) if not callable(getattr(a, attribute))]

output: ['T', '__array_finalize__', '__array_interface__', '__array_priority__', '__array_struct__', '__doc__', '__hash__', 'base', 'ctypes', 'data', 'dtype', 'flags', 'flat', 'imag', 'itemsize', 'nbytes', 'ndim', 'real', 'shape', 'size', 'strides']
```

And if you want to avoid the protected attributes:

```
attribute_list = [attribute for attribute in dir(a) if not callable(getattr(a, attribute)) and attribute[0] != '_']


output: ['T', 'base', 'ctypes', 'data', 'dtype', 'flags', 'flat', 'imag', 'itemsize', 'nbytes', 'ndim', 'real', 'shape', 'size', 'strides']
```

Comment: I thought there is kind of a shortcut for this, like dir() is for returning all attributes of an object. Nervertheless your answer does what I asked for, so thank you!